# Braintree - Form validation before opening the lightbox

Tags: braintree

This is the first time I am implementing Braintree.js, I am using "Add PayPal button" approach to display the PayPal button on the page. Once the PayPal button is generated (by passing braintree token) I need to invoke some Ajax function to validate the form fields and once these are validated then only want to open the PayPal lightbox and get the nonce value after the final submit on the lightbox. How do I implement the ajax call using the braintree generated "PayPal" button BEFORE opening the lightbox. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Can you provide more information to help get this solved? Samples of the code you're using to generate the button would help.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is not a callback that fires before the PayPal lightbox or popup opens.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it sounds like you want to use the PayPal button as your form's submit button, which is not that button's intended function.  Using Braintree's PayPal integration returns a nonce which you can then submit along with rest of your form as a separate action. When a user submits the form, you can validate that your form fields are valid, and that a nonce has been successfully generated before submitting it.

For a more in-depth description of integrating with PayPal visit [Braintree's PayPal Guide](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+ruby/guides/paypal).

Let me know if you have any other questions.